# "Owning" a large Tech-Group on Facebook - Part of my portfolio?

Tags: hiring-process, references

I'm running one of the largest "Computer - Software - Hardware" Groups on facebook in my country (~20k member), where people help people with their computer problems, talk about all computer related stuff, newest trends, newest hardware and so on.

I'd say a good 50% is user to user support.
In regard of general PC-Problems (Not booting, crashing, which CPU would be the best upgrade,...).
30% is discussing consumer trends (Look at this fancy case InWin just put on the market!,...)
20% is professional related stuff like "how do I this or that on our exchange".

Is it a good idea to mention this in a hiring process?
I'm a generalist and doing jobs like IT-Project Management. My knowledge is very broad but not as deep as a specialists.

After all, what is this even worth?

Comment: related? [How should I list my SE moderator position on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/how-should-i-list-my-se-moderator-position-on-my-resume)

Comment: Also similar, [Should I list a technology blog on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/should-i-list-a-technology-blog-on-my-resume).

Comment: My first question as employer would be: How much time do you spend moderating this?

Comment: @Daniel This is a good question. In this time, where one is online at almost any time, I can spend a minute here and there without it costing me a lot of effort in generall. I'd say, the moderation itself consumes about 2-3 hours per week. Then there are another 1-10 hours /week of personal participation in the discussions.

Comment: @Sempie: And with that answer I would seriously think about nor hiring you, because I would suspect you´d be distracted by this group during work-hours. Be careful there!

Answer (score 7):

If this group isn't relevant to the job you're going for, then obviously don't list it (it's not relevant).

Think about how relevant this social group is with the jobs that you're interviewing for and how hiring manager will see this voluntary use of the internet as a help group.  Be really aware of how the hiring manager will see this.  It's natural for them to think that you'd be spending periods administering this group when you should be spending that time working for them.  Also, the value you give to this group in no way benefits the company you're working for (or very little).

Although it's great to see that you're volunteering your time, you should be careful about how you pitch this.

Think about adding this to the end of your resume as a "Volunteer" task that removes itself from being a key part of your life.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to mention this in a hiring process?

Unless the position your applying for is **directly** related I would not recommend listing it, period.

> After all, what is this even worth?

I would say not a whole lot or nothing, **unless** your applying for a position where you are managing an online group or community.